# Why does setting a MessageListener on a MessageConsumer not cause the program to continue after the main thread dies?

Tags: java, jms, message-listener

I am setting up a MessageListener and expect that the program will still run (since the listening thread is still alive), but after "Finished" is printed on the screen, the program is terminated. Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

```
    MessageListener messageListener = new DelegationReceiver();
    Properties p = PropertiesLoader.getProperties("jms.properties");
    InitialContext cntxt = new InitialContext();

    cntxt.addToEnvironment(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, p.getProperty("namingFactory"));
    cntxt.addToEnvironment(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, p.getProperty("urlPackages"));
    cntxt.addToEnvironment(Context.PROVIDER_URL,p.getProperty("providerURL"));
    cntxt.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"default");
    cntxt.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"password");
    ConnectionFactory tfact = (ConnectionFactory) cntxt.lookup(p.getProperty("topicFactory"));
    Topic topic = (Topic) cntxt.lookup(p.getProperty("myTopic"));
    Connection connection = tfact.createConnection();
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    MessageConsumer mc = session.createConsumer(topic);
    mc.setMessageListener(messageListener);
    connection.start();
    System.out.println("Finished");
```

Comment: Apologies. This is the entirety of the main method. and the DelegationReceiver constructor does nothing.

Comment: And the topic is set up on JBoss EAP 5.2.0

Comment: Unless DelegationReceiver is a non-daemon thread there is nothing to be surprised at here.

Comment: I was previously using Glassfish and this same code did not terminate. I guess Glassfish makes the Consumers non-daemon? ... I guess question then is to how to set up the program so that all it does is listen to the Topic? My only solution thus far is to have a System.in.read() that waits for input before closing the connections and terminating. Is there a better way?